# MSBuild not assigning version number

Tags: msbuild, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am using the following command in azure pipelines to apply a PackageVersion to the outputted DLLs. The PackageVersion is not coming through and I can't tell if it's because another configuration is overwritting it or something else. The PackageVersion (the AssemblyInfoVersion in c# is always the default 1.0.0)

```
    - task: MSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build solution eCommerceAPI.sln'
      inputs:
        solution: eCommerceAPI.sln
        msbuildArchitecture: x64
        configuration: Release
        msbuildArguments: '/p:DebugType=none /p:DebugSymbols=false  /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package  /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true  /p:DeployAsIisApp=False /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/eCommerceAPI" /p:PackageLocation=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"\eCommerceAPI.zip" /p:PackageVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Including the csproj as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="JWT" Version="6.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <DocumentationFile>$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml</DocumentationFile>
    <UserSecretsId>11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hi @TeaBaerd. How do you define the packageversion parameter in csproj? You could share the csproj content with us .What framework is your project based on？

Comment: I am not assigning the version in any other way than as the parameter at build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PackageVersion does not update the versions associated with the assemblies but the Version parameter will assign the version to all assemblies.